# Why didn't Harry's touch hurt Voldemort in "HP and the Deathly Hallows"?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, voldemort

I watched some of the Harry Potter movies today, and there is something I didn't understand.

In the first movie, Harry's touch hurts Professor Quirrell, but when Voldemort and Harry "fall-fly" during the last scene, the touch doesn't seem to affect him.
Is there a canon reason as to why?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpFIj_8daVU#t=29

Comment: Thanks. As I said I re-watched SOME of the movies today, and this was one of the ones that I skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voldemort could not touch Harry because of the protective magic that lay on Harry through his mothers sacrifice. In book four, Voldemort has Peter use Harry's blood to resurrect his body, thereby negating the protective magic that Harry had in his blood, or rather sharing that magic with Voldemort. Voldemort actually touches Harry in book four after this to show that he can now touch Harry without consequence.